# Creating an Azure server Database failed

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I just signed up with Microsoft Azure. I want to upload my existing database onto the cloud. I don't see any create any server instance in the Sql Server menu. I have tried using the add new database procedure. I have completed all the steps but the process keeps failing. This is my status error message:

> {"error":{"code":"DisallowedProvider","message":"The operation is not
>   permitted for namespace 'Microsoft.Sql'. List of permitted provider
>   namespaces is
>   'Microsoft.Resources,Microsoft.Authorization, Microsoft.Insights, Microsoft.Web, Microsoft.Support, Microsoft.VisualStudio, SuccessBricks.ClearDB, Microsoft.NotificationHubs'."}}

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 6):

If you are using dreamspark account that currently Microsoft don't support SQL for dreamspark account users.

Answer (score 1):

What version of the portal are you using? Since there are a few different ways you can proceed about creating a SQL database, I recommend following this tutorial to start with Azure SQL Database: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-get-started/

If you have an existing SQL Server database and would like to migrate it to SQL Azure you can use SQL Migration Wizard, or script your existing database and execute the script with SSMS. A few more alternatives can be found here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-cloud-migrate/

Hope this helps!

Thanks,
Luis